# Можно ли передать адрес от числа, не создавая переменную?

Tags: c, указатели

**Пример:** у меня есть ф-ция вывода на экран массива, которая принимает указатель, и длину. Я могу, не создавая отдельной переменную, сразу передать число как аргумент?
Может я должен переделать ф-цию **print**, например первый параметр: `const uint8_t* mass` или еще как нибудь? Я гарантирую, что ф-ция **print** будет только читать значения, и не будет их менять!

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void print(uint8_t * mass, uint16_t len)
{
    uint16_t i;
    for (i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        cout << mass[i];
    }
    cout << endl;
}

int main()
{
    print(&((uint8_t)0),1);
    return 0;
}
```

Пока у меня не получилось, надеюсь на вашу помощь.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Если массив состоит из однобайтовых значений, то можно вместо символа передать строку: https://ideone.com/hP60jc

```
#include <stdio.h>

void print(unsigned char *a, size_t n)
{
  unsigned char *end;

  for (end=a+n; a<end; ++a)
    putchar(*a);

  putchar('\n');
}

int main()
{
  print((unsigned char*)"Q", 1);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: а тут можно число передавать? как число превратить в односимвольную строку?

Comment: @KtoTo, `uint8_t` - это и есть `unsigned char`. Чтобы передать число 42 (оно же 0x2A) надо передать строку `"\x2A"`. Для многобайтовых типов - лучше не связываться с этим способом.

Comment: не знал конструкцию "\x00". Спасибо! То что надо!

Comment: @KtoTo, если надо именно один нолик, то можно просто `""`, потому что строка и так завершается нулём в си.

Comment: [Разочарованно] ну, это неспортивно... Функция хочет массив, ей передают массив...

Answer (score 7):

Поскольку вы спрашиваете с двумя тэгами - и C, и C++, не буду рассказывать, что такое rvalue, lvalue и прочие (но рекомендую самому поинтересоваться).

А вам просто задам вопрос - просто число - это какое-то значение, которое может быть просто записано в команде процессору - ну, например,

```
mov eax, 0
```

т.е. этот ноль - это просто байты *не в данных, а в выполнимом коде* - вы считаете, что этот адрес, приходящийся на средину команды, может что-то дать полезное? При том, что обращаться к коду - это в общем случае запрещено?

Или это может быть значение в регистре процессора - как вы себе представляете его адрес?

Опять же, представим вызов - `f(&1,&1,&1)` - это три разных адреса единиц или один и тот же?

Поэтому в общем случае - нет, адрес **числа вообще** - это нонсенс.

*Что бы вы ни получили в качестве корректного адреса и каким путем - это будет переменная, содержащая нужное вам значение, пусть даже она будет временная и безымянная.*

Очень хромой костыль:

```
char * addr(char q)
{
    static char c;
    c = q;
    return &c;
}

void print(char * a)
{
    printf("[%c]\n",*a);
}

int main()
{
    print(addr('Q'));
}
```

Но он мне активно не нравится :) И это уж точно не "адрес числа", а адрес статической переменной в другой функции... Но руками создавать переменную при этом не приходится.

Еще вариант - раз уж все равно устраивает написание дополнительных функций :)

```
void print(char * a);
void printChar(char a) { print &a; }
```

Comment: Загляни в мой ответ - не пойму, можно так делать, или нельзя? Ну помимо снятия const.

Comment: _"Поскольку вы спрашиваете с двумя тэгами"_ - изначально в вопросе был только си, я добавил плюсы из-за cout'а.

Comment: @Qwertiy Да смотрю и никак не соображу :) Я бы такое использовать никому не рекомендовал, но тем не менее `const&` разрешается использовать. Скорее всего, создается какая-то временная переменная, которая потом благополучно уничтожается. Т.е. формально - это не адрес числа, а адрес временного места в памяти?

Comment: _"это будет переменная ... временная и безымянная"_ - ну так вопрос в том, чтоб в коде её самому не объявлять, а уж что она там где-то внутри создастся - вроде неважно? А то так можно про что угодно сказать, что оно где-то хранится.

Comment: @Qwertiy Вот вариант - https://ideone.com/JIFmj8 - но, по мне, это все же извращение. И в строгом смысле - создание переменной.

Comment: Ну `static char` - это же нельзя рекурсивно использовать))

Comment: @Qwertiy А как еще преодолеть границы времени жизни переменной? Работать на низком уровне с ассемблерными вставками? Выделить сразу большой пул для таких переменных? Или написать другую функцию, которая вызывает нашу (какая разница, кто кого? - см. в ответе дополнение). Но это все - все равно создание переменных...

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67170/discussion-between-qwertiy-and-harry).

Answer (score 5):

У меня какой-то костыль получился, но я понятия не имею, насколько правильно так делать, и приводит ли это к UB или нет. Также обращаю внимание, что я убираю `const` для совместимости с вызываемой функций, чего делать не стоит. Если функция не меняет данные, её параметр уже должен быть объявлен с модификатором `const`, а если меняет, то с какого перепуга ей передавать указатель на rvalue?

> **Вопрос о наличии UB, связанного в указателем:
>
>   [Продление жизни значения константной ссылкой](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/731506/178988)**

https://ideone.com/UTkkzK

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template <typename T> T * ref(const T &x) {
  return (T*)(&x);
}

void print(uint8_t *&&mass, size_t n)
{
  for (size_t q=0; q<n; ++q)
    cout << mass[q];

  cout << endl;
}

int main()
{
  print(ref((uint8_t)'Q'), 1);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Тут временный объект создается, его адрес и попадает в print

Comment: @Cerbo, я понимаю. В вопросе именно это и нужно. Но я не понимаю, это UB или нет?

Comment: именно это и нужно!.. А теперь еще на си=)

Comment: @KtoTo, не уверен, что на си такое возможно.

Comment: @Qwertiy В вопросе сказано ".. не создавая перменную", так что как раз это не нужно.

Comment: @Cerbo, а где ты видишь переменную в коде? И вообще, спорить с тем, это нужно или нет, когда автор вопроса в соседнем комментарии сказал, что нужно именно это - это как-то странно.

Comment: Забавно - VC++ вносит в стек значение, потом берет его адрес, и тоже заносит в стек - если я правильно разобрался в ассемблерном коде...

Comment: @Harry, звучит как ожидаемое поведение. Или это по какой-то причине странно?

Comment: Я еще не успел дописать - это переменная создается как *локальная* переменная в функции `main` - в ее стеке. Так что формально она видна и дальше. Сейчас попробую посмотреть, будет ли она одна на 2 вызова... Посмотрел - нет, это две разные переменные (в режиме без оптимизации /Od)

Comment: @Harry, по-прежнему считаю это ожидаемым поведением. `const &` именно так и работают ведь по стандарту - время их жизни продлевается до времени жизни ссылки. Дальше - это где? Насколько я понимаю, эта штука обязана жить один вызов функции, только не пойму, какой - `ref` или `print`.

Comment: В режиме без отладки, будучи локальной переменной в `main()`, она живет до конца программы :) С отладкой - правда, я немного поменял код - компилятор оказался достаточно умным чтоб сразу использовать конкретное значение, не тратя время на вычисление его адреса. Что до UB - то кроме снятия `const`, я его не вижу. Но красивый вопрос :)

Comment: @Harry, возможно, стандарт предписывает переменной жить только пока выполняется `ref` - в таком случае в `print` попадёт битый указатель. А возможно, нет. Надо поискать кусок стандарта про продление жизни константых ссылок.

Comment: @Qwertiy Ну мы же уже передаем в `ref` ссылку - значит, жить ей столько, сколько жива эта ссылка... с другой стороны, хоть она и в вызове `print` - но и в самом деле по выходу из `ref` ее время жизни должно окончиться. Да, какое-то спорное место... Непонятно, когда и на какой срок компилятор создает временную переменную.

Comment: @Harry, угу, я именно про этот момент. Обязана ли она дожить до print?