# Продление жизни значения константной ссылкой

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++, ссылки, language-lawyer, неопределённое-поведение

Как известно, если rvalue передаётся в некую функцию через константную ссылку, то время его жизни продлевается. Т. е. в следующем примере оно точно живёт пока выполняется функция `ref_to_ptr`. Вопрос в том, насколько долго обязано жить такое значение и допустимо ли его использование в функции `print`, либо же это UB с разыменованием потенциально мусорного указателя?

https://ideone.com/CcacHz

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template <typename T> const T *ref_to_ptr(const T &x)
{
  return &x;
}

void print(const int *val)
{
  cout << *val << endl;
}

int main()
{
  print(ref_to_ptr(42));
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Мне кажется, что UB, обосновать не могу (покамест)

Comment: [Чат для этого и связанного вопросов](//chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67170/discussion-between-qwertiy-and-harry)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Насколько я понимаю [стандарт](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.temporary#6.9) (цитата):

> ⁴ [...] Temporary objects are destroyed as the last step in evaluating the full-expression that (lexically) contains the point where they were created. [...]
>
> ⁵ There are three contexts in which temporaries are destroyed at a different point than the end of the full-expression. [...]
>
> ⁶ The third context is when a reference is bound to a temporary object. 
>   The temporary object to which the reference is bound or the temporary object that is the complete object of a subobject to which the reference is bound persists for the lifetime of the reference [...] 
>   The exceptions to this lifetime rule are:
>
> (6.9) — A temporary object bound to a reference parameter in a function call persists until the completion of the full-expression containing the call.
>
> (6.10) — The lifetime of a temporary bound to the returned value in a function return statement is not extended; the temporary is destroyed at the end of the full-expression in the return statement.

Иными словами: обычно временный объект, на который ссылается ссылка, умирает вместе со ссылкой. Но если вы передаёте в функцию временный объект как аргумент для ref-параметра, время жизни этого временного объекта продлевается до конца всего выражения, содержащего вызов функции.

Это значит, что время жизни параметра `x` заканчивается в конце строки

```
print(ref_to_ptr(42));
```

то есть доступа к «умершему» объекту нет.

Это также, судя по всему, означает, что переписав код следующим образом:

```
const int *ptr = ref_to_ptr(42);
print(ptr);
```

вы получите таки undefined behaviour, т. к. время жизни временного объекта, на который указывает `ptr`, заканчивается после первой строки!

Comment: Временные объекты и так живут до конца full expression.

Comment: @Croessmah: А вот стандарт, кажется, говорит «The temporary object to which the reference is bound [...] persists for the lifetime of the reference». То есть без исключения время жизни было бы короче.

Comment: нет, это относится несколько к другому случаю.

Comment: Some const & ref = A+B;//A+B дает временный объект, и в данном случае он привязывается к ссылке. Время жизни этого временного объекта продлевается - он будет жить до смерти ссылки ref. Временные объекты живут до конца full expression, а продление жизни как раз позволяет сделать так, что после full expression объект будет жить дальше.

Comment: @Croessmah: Странно, а к какому? Можете привести цитату из стандарта? В нашем случае время жизни ссылки _меньше_, чем full expression.

Comment: "Temporary objects are destroyed as the last step in evaluating the full-expression (4.6) that (lexically) contains the point where they were created. This is true even if that evaluation ends in throwing an exception. The value computations and side effects of destroying a temporary object are associated only with the full-expression, not with any specific subexpression.". То есть все временные объекты живут до конца full-expression. Но, есть три контекста, где это не так. Один из них - привязывание к ссылке, как я показал выше.

Comment: @Croessmah: А, вы вне контекста привязки к ссылке? Тогда да.

Comment: что касается параметра функции, то продления времени жизни не происходит и "The exceptions to this lifetime rule are: A temporary object bound to a reference parameter in a function call (8.2.2) persists until the completion of the full-expression containing the call."

Comment: @Croessmah: Ну это как раз и смысл моего ответа.

Answer (score 5):

Добавлю критерий истины :) - практику. В подтверждение точки зрения @VladD приведу такой код:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template <typename T> const T *ref_to_ptr(const T &x)
{
  return &x;
}

class Test
{
public:
    Test()  { cout << "ctor: " << this << endl; }
    ~Test() { cout << "dtor: " << this << endl; }
};

void print(const Test * val)
{
    cout << val << endl;
}

int main()
{
    print(ref_to_ptr(Test()));
    const Test * ptr = ref_to_ptr(Test());
    print(ptr);
    cout << "The end.\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Сей [код](https://ideone.com/xvgxdD) ведет себя одинаково в VC++ и в GCC, демонстрируя, что временный объект умирает уже после вызова `print`, но сразу же после него.

Comment: Ага, а ещё адрес один и тот же)