# Вызов деструктора и оптимизации компилятора

Tags: c++

Все мы знаем, что неиспользуемые переменные могут быть выброшены компилятором, как например переменная `i` ниже:

```cpp
int main() {
  int a = 10;
  int i = 15;

  std::cout << a << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Меня же интересует может ли компилятор вызвать деструктор раньше, чем переменная покинет область видимость (к примеру после последнего его использования). Особенно интересует следующая ситуация:

```cpp
int foo() {
  static std::mutex mutex;
  std::lock_guard<std::mutex>{mutex};
  ... some code ...

  return 0;
}
```

Тобишь: возможна ли, в данном случае, что мьютекс освободится раньше, чем произойдет выход из функции?

Comment: Нет, не может - mutex является частью стандартной библиотеки, а не синтаксической конструкцией языка

Comment: @ТрипольскийПётр это понятно, что mutex - не часть языка, а часть stl (с 11-ого стандарта), но я не понимаю как это относится к вопросу

Comment: @Трипольский Пётр, да, действительно без  mutex а в языке ничго не изменится, но я тоже не вижу связь этого обстоятельства с вопросом. Но согласен с тем, что компилятор его никак не освободит

Comment: в конкретно этом примере вы используете мьютекс, std::lock_guard вызывает методы lock() / unlock(), так что он точно не будет оптимизирован

Comment: Нет - нарушение as is.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Не может потому что в конструкторе и деструкторе есть побочные эффекты, которые компилятор трогать не имеет права.

---

Поскольку лок создаётся без имени, его областью видимости является текущий statement и он просуществует [ровно до конца него](//ru.stackoverflow.com/a/731529/178988). Скорее всего компилятор его всё равно выкинуть не может, но в данном случает при отсутствии каких-либо ещё действий в рамках statement'а это неважно.

Comment: Да, все так, но в вопросе (точнее в коде) есть ещё один важный момент: lock_guard создаётся без имени. И как показал эксперимент с кастомным классом, деструктор в подобном случае вызывается сразу же после создания объекта. То бишь для данного случая (не касаясь as if rule) мьютекс будет освобождён до выхода из функции. Не знаете, что о таких ситуациях говорит стандарт?

Comment: Блин, не заметил. Знаю. До конца statement:  https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/731529/178988.

Comment: Я обновил ответ.

Answer (score 11):

http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.stc.auto#3

> "Если переменная с автоматическим классом памяти имеет инициализацию или деструктор с побочными эффектами, **реализация не имеет права** ни **уничтожить ее раньше достижения конца ее блока**, ни полностью убрать ее в процессе оптимизации, даже если переменная выглядит неиспользуемой; за исключением того, что копирование/перемещение объекта класса может быть устранено в соответствии с правилами [class.copy.elision]"

Разумеется, это правило Абстрактной С++ Машины, которое может быть обойдено в рамках правила "as if", но не в таких случаях. Реализация прекрасно знает, что взаимодействие с синхронизационным объектом может влиять на наблюдаемое поведение программы.

Comment: Да, все так, но в вопросе (точнее в коде) есть ещё один важный момент: lock_guard создаётся без имени. И как показал эксперимент с кастомным классом, деструктор в подобном случае вызывается сразу же после создания объекта. То бишь для данного случая (не касаясь as if rule) мьютекс будет освобождён до выхода из функции. Не знаете, что о таких ситуациях говорит стандарт?

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch, [до конца stateent](//ru.stackoverflow.com/a/731529/178988).

Answer (score 10):

Компилятор может убрать `int a = 10;` не потому, что к нему нет обращений в программе, а потому, что его наличие не влияет на поведение программы. Это называется the [**as-if rule**](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/as_if).

Наличие `lock_guard`-а влияет на поведение программы, поэтому as-if rule не позволяет его убрать.

Comment: Разве as-if rule применимо к многопоточной среде? Там вроде какое-то другое должно быть?

Comment: @Qwertiy Могу ошибаться, но думаю применимо.

Comment: @Qwertiy♦: А почему бы и нет? Правило as-if опирается на правила sequencing. А правила sequencing сами по себе уже адаптированы для целей многопоточной среды. То есть основная сложность тут заключается именно в формулировке правил sequencing. А когда это уже сделано, то as-if сохраняется натуральным образом.

Comment: Да, все так, но в вопросе (точнее в коде) есть ещё один важный момент: lock_guard создаётся без имени. И как показал эксперимент с кастомным классом, деструктор в подобном случае вызывается сразу же после создания объекта. То бишь для данного случая (не касаясь as if rule) мьютекс будет освобождён до выхода из функции. Не знаете, что о таких ситуациях говорит стандарт?

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch, [до конца stateent](//ru.stackoverflow.com/a/731529/178988).

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch Не обратил внимание. Раз без имени, то он считается временным объектом и удаляется, когда заканчивается вычисление выражения (["full expression"](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lifetime)), где он был создан.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, или тот пункт тут неприменим?

Comment: @Qwertiy Применим, и там как раз написано, что до конца full-expression.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, а full expression == statement в данном случае?

Comment: @Qwertiy Вроде не всегда. Скажем, `if (foo) {...}` - это один большой statement, а `foo` - full expression. Если в `foo` создать временный объект, он удалится до захода в тело if, а не после.

Comment: А в случае `std::lock_guard<std::mutex>{mutex};` - да, одно и то же.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, а в случае `(std::lock_guard<std::mutex>{mutex}), doSmth();`?

Comment: @Qwertiy Здесь тоже совпадают, должна уничтожится после вызова `doSmth()`.