# Доступ к аргументам функции извне. Возможно ли?

Tags: c

Даны функции и структура:

```
typedef struct s_list
{
    void            *content;
    struct s_list   *next;
}   t_list;

t_list  *ft_lstnew(void *content);                // создает новый элемент списка;
void    ft_lstadd_back(t_list **lst, t_list *new);// добавляет элемент в конец списка;
t_list  *ft_lstlast(t_list *lst);                 // возвращает указатель на последний элемент списка;
int     get_next_line(int fd, char **line);       //записывает в строку по данному адресу следующую строку, считанную (например) с файла до '\n' включительно;
```

Я хочу получать новые строки и сразу же их записывать во вновь созданный новый элемент списка. Но не знаю как это сделать в одну строку.
Далее - ход моих размышлений.
Казалось бы можно так:

```
get_next_line(fd, (char**)&(mylist->content));
```

Но при `mylist == NULL` - не выйдет. Получается нужно создать новый элемент и записать уже в него:

```
get_next_line(fd, (char**)&(ft_lstnew(NULL)->content));
```

- тоже не то - так как я теряю адрес этого нового элемента.
Пойдем дальше:

```
get_next_line(fd, (char**)&(mylist = ft_lstnew(NULL))->content));
```

Здесь похоже на правду, но все же это не элемент списка, а структура.

И вот тут я в затруднительном положении. Мне не удается вызвать void-функцию `ft_lstaddback(&head, ft_lstnew(NULL));` и извлечь из нее адрес последнего элемента.

Отсюда и вопрос - есть ли возможность извлечь адрес аргумента извне void-функции?

Comment: "но все же это не элемент списка, а структура" разве структура не представляет элемент списка?

Comment: @dimonbavly В чем вопрос , получаете указатель на свободный элемент списка и записываете в него строку.

Comment: 1.согласен, но при повторном вызове в цикле этой-же функции - я теряю адрес предыущего элемента списка , причем это будет уже другой одноэлементный список.

Comment: 2. дело в том что я не могу получить указатель на свободный элемент, так как его нет и он создается при вызове ft_lstnew()

Comment: А с чего такое желание именно в одну строку? чтоб непонятнее выглядело?

Comment: в проекте есть ограничение на количество строк функции. да и в академических целях.

Comment: @Mikhailo, иногда может быть надо... https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/731529/178988

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего так:

```
s_list *mylist = 0, *last = 0;

get_next_line(
  fd,
  (char*)(
    last
    ? (ft_lstaddback(last, last = ft_lstnew(0)), last)
    : (mylist = last = ft_lstnew(0))
  )->content)
);
```